Unobtrusive Ajax link with Blazor Static SSR pages
I have a Main SSR Page that renders a component that has a jquery unobtrusive ajax link:
@if (rndvar != 0)
{
    <h3>Ajax Get Link</h3>
    <a method="get" 
       data-ajax="true"
       data-ajax-method="get" data-ajax-mode="replace"
       data-ajax-update="#ajax-update-link"
       data-ajax-loading="#spinner"
       data-ajax-success="javascript:window.pageFunctions.ajaxLinkSuccess()"
       data-ajax-url="/Tests/ajax-link/@rndvar"
       id="lnkAjax" style="text-decoration: underline; color: blue; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;">            
            Ajax Link @rndvar              
    </a>
}

The component page (StaticSSRLink.razor) that this posts is:
@page "/Tests/ajax-link/{Id:int}"
@layout StaticSSRComponentLayout
@attribute [ExcludeFromInteractiveRouting]

@if (Id != 0)
{
    <h3>Id * 2 = @result</h3>
}


@code {

    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    int result = 0;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        result = Id * 2;
    }    
}

the StaticSSRComponentLayout is a simple layout with only some markup.
In the Main SSR Page that has the div to replace with ajax content I have:
..

<PageScript Src="./Pages/Tests/StaticSSR/StaticSSRPage.razor.js"></PageScript>

..

<div id="ajax-update-link">
    <StaticSSRLink Id="0"></StaticSSRLink>
</div>

To be complete this is the layout that StaticSSRLink uses: (StaticSSRComponentLayout.razor):
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@attribute [ExcludeFromInteractiveRouting]

<SectionContent SectionName="Ajax">
    <script src="lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive-main/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
</SectionContent>


<div id="mydiv">
    @{
        string direction = loc["Direction"];
    }
    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(direction))
    {
        <div dir="@direction" style="text-align: start;">
            @Body
        </div>
    }
</div>

The Problem: while this works and with any number of <a../> clicks shows a single resulting HTML page and expected HTML each time, But with every click of the <a../>, a power of 2 requests made to the server. for example, the first time: 2^1, second time: 2^2 and so on.
Is there any way to not to have these too many requests?
